# In python 27 how do I pass a method with arguments to a class's __init__()?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, module, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a parameter to a function that I want to call from an instance of a class but I have no idea how to do it. I can do it just fine if I don't pass any params but the second I start passing params it all blows up in my face.

Here is an example of what I want to do.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, use_function=None):
        self.use_function = use_function

    def call(self):
        self.use_function()

def bar(number):
    print 'number is ' + str(number)

myObj = foo( use_function=bar(15) )

myObj.call()
```

Comment: What do you mean "it blows up in my face"?  What do you expect that example to do, and what does it do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass the arguments, because your `__init__` function doesn't accept the arguments, it just accepts the function.  If you pass `bar(15)`, it calls `bar` *before* `__init__`, and `__init__` receives the *return value* of `bar(15)` (which in this case is None).

If what you want is for `__init__` to call `bar(15)`, you can do `foo( use_function=lambda: bar(15) )`.  This will pass to `__init__` a zero-argumenbt function that, when called, will call `bar(15)`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Now I am going to have to go figure out what you just did so I can understand it before adding it to my code. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, use_function=None,params=None):
        self.use_function = use_function
        self.params = params

    def call(self):
        self.use_function(self.params)

def bar(number):
    print 'number is ' + str(number)

myObj = foo( use_function=bar, params=15 )

myObj.call()
```

Comment: If you want to support multiple parameters (and not just one misleadingly named with a plural), you probably want to do `self.use_function(*self.params)` in `call` and pass `params=(15,)` (a one-element tuple) to the `foo` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, use_function=None):
        self.use_function = use_function

    def call(self):
        eval(self.use_function)

def bar(number):
    print 'number is ' + str(number)

myObj = foo( use_function="bar(15)" )

myObj.call()
```

If you want pass the parameter to the function, when pass the function to `init`, you can pass a string like `bar(15)`, the place where you want to call the function, just use built-in function `eval`

Answer (score 0):

You can return the value which you're printing in bar()

```
class foo:
  def __init__(self,use_func=None):
    self.u = use_func
  def call(self):
    print self.u

def bar(n):
 return n

myobj = foo(use_func=bar(15))
myobj.call()
```

All because you're not passing anything from bar() the myobj gets None